# Framework7 widget injection from server

Tags: widget, code-injection, html-framework-7

I am Framework7 newbie. I am migrating normal javascript into Framework7.

After page loaded, my javascript code load widgets(Button,Text,Slider...) from Server and inject it into the page. I use append() function to append them into a div

Somehow, some widgets are not working. For example, range-slider. I find out that it need to be rendered by Framework7 in order to work properly.

Please advise.